# Asynchronous Programming: yield vs async/await

Tags: javascript, asynchronous, async-await, yield

I would like to know which is the best solution when using asynchronous programming. Which one should I use?

Comment: Avoid any tutorials that still advocate `yield` for asynchronous programming with promises, they are totally outdated.

Comment: Like the name suggests, [async/await](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/async_function) are specifically designed for asynchronous programming. [Yield](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/function*) is meant to be used in generator functions. Yield is still useful on this date, but not for asynchronous programming.

Comment: _yield_ is tied to _Generators_ which can be combined to Promises to handle asynchronous iterations … This pattern is now considered obsolete so to speak since _async/await_ construct is now supported by JavaScript runtimes. [Quote from Mozilla developper network](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/async_function) : «…Just as Promises are similar to structured callbacks, async/await is similar to combining generators and promises.»

Answer (score 2):

Always use `async/await` for asynchronous tasks.

Yield should only be used for generator functions. Read [this article](https://medium.com/dailyjs/a-simple-guide-to-understanding-javascript-es6-generators-d1c350551950) on when and how to use (it's worth the time).